# Have we cottoned on to [organic-food] needing to be renamed?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

[organic-food](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic-food) should be renamed to [organic-farming](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic-farming) to cover farming that doesn't involve food, such as [cotton farming](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39844/does-organic-cotton-use-less-water-than-conventional-cotton).

Previous meta questions about organic farming: [Tag merge request: 'organic' and 'biofood'](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2342/tag-merge-request-organic-and-biofood) (renaming "biofoods" to "organic") and [Dealing with incorrect terminology](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1115/dealing-with-incorrect-terminology) (complaining about the use of the word "organic").